# how to clear Interval on Mouse Over in java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, mouseover

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var images=["cod.jpg","cod2.jpg","cod3.jpg","cod4.jpg"];
var i=0;
window.onload=function(){
changeimage();
var stopinterval = setInterval(changeimage,3000);
}
function changeimage(){
if(i==images.length||i>images.length){
    i=0;
}

document.getElementById('metroslider').src=images[i];
i++;

}
function stopanim(){
    clearInterval(stopinterval);
    }
</script>
```

**body is below **

```
<div class="sliderbtns" onMouseMove="stopanim();">
```

**But its not working please help me how to stop the interval using On mousOver function .
Thanks .**

Comment: Declare `stopinterval` variable outerside `window.onload` and bind `mouseleave` or `mouseout` event

Comment: yeah thanks bro...it works but how to start it again ?? i added a mouseOut function but its not working !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var images = ["cod.jpg", "cod2.jpg", "cod3.jpg", "cod4.jpg"];
var i = 0;
var stopinterval;
window.onload = function() {
  changeimage();
  stopinterval = setInterval(changeimage, 333);
}

function changeimage() {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = i;
  i++;

}

function startAnim() {
  if (stopinterval === null) { 
    stopinterval = setInterval(changeimage, 333);
  }
}

function stopanim() {
  if (stopinterval) { 
    clearInterval(stopinterval);
    stopinterval = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="stopanim()" onmouseout="startAnim()">mouse over to stop</div>
```

Comment: As you notice stopinterval is declared as a global variable. Otherwise stopanim() can't access it.

Comment: yeah thanks bro...it works but how to start it again ?? i added a mouseOut function but its not working !!

Comment: Yeah now its working well...thanks Dear.....but i have a confusion if you can explain Why we used "if" condition for stopping animation although in first case it was stopped just by clearing interval ???? why only this dose not works ....  function stopanim()  { 
    clearInterval(stopinterval);
    stopinterval = null;
  }
}

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS you will have the same result without the "if". I'm just used to check everything before anything so... if you want just to clear the interval in stopanim() just ignore the if(stopinterval) condition.